# MYSQL increment suffix letter with UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql-update, field, increment

I have fields in a mysql database witch contains numbers followed by a suffix composed with an underscore and letter Ex : 04563_a;

What i would like is an UPDATE request that would increment
04563_a to 04563_b

Is it something that can be done with one UPDATE query?

Thanks

Comment: What if the number is `04563_z` ?

Comment: In my specific case it will never reach _z. But good question!
_aa, _ab, would be great.